To what extent is it possible to mimic absentmindedness in competitive, two-player game design?
Absentmindedness occurs in a game when a player has imperfect recall of which game state in a playthrough is current.  For example, in the Absent Minded Driver Problem, a driver values turning at the first of two consecutive intersections the same as receiving $0, turning at the second the same as $4, and driving straight through both the same as $1, but (knowingly) will not recall whether an intersection has already been passed when deciding whether to turn (extending this to many consecutive intersections makes it more realistic).  Absentmindedness produces at least two unintuitive strategic ideas, which may be interesting to try to instantiate in a concrete game (driver-themed example is continued below but need not be in the concrete game).

Since the driver will not recall whether the game is in the first intersection state or the second intersection state, the decision to turn or drive straight cannot differ as a function of this information.  The central paradox of absentmindedness is that evaluated before playing, maximizing expected value seems to warrant driving straight, because planning to turn at both intersections is worth $0 (which is less than $1), but evaluated at an unknown intersection, maximizing expected value seems to warrant abandoning the prior "drive straight" strategy and turning, because turning without any information to disambiguate between the two intersections is worth an average of $2 (which is greater than $1). Hence concrete game design may be able to place a player in a game state in which there appear to be two competing notions of maximizing the expected value of a game action.

Depending on the details of the model (as explicated in the above paper), a player who knowingly will not be able to recall the identity of the current intersection but can change and recall strategies may be incentivized to use strategy as a tool to encode information in a form available to their future self.  Hence concrete game design may be able to incentivize a player at the (metaphorical) first intersection to make trade-offs in their strategy between striving for backward induction (making the "optimal play" given perfect recall) and implicitly communicating some of the information which will be forgotten to their future self.


The challenge is that no one has invented a magic wand to make players forget things (or recall them after the decision is made if necessary to progress the game), so I have to try to mimic one.  I'll exclude some relatively obvious approaches.  If a concrete game is more about roleplaying than competing, then the players could just pretend to forget information.  If there are teams of players and communication between players on a team is limited, then the team personified can be induced to "forget" information by switching the individual decision maker.  Let's instead assume we're making a competitive, two-player game, perhaps a Trading Card Game.
One watered down approach could involve removing, and instead automatically applying, an extremely simple decision.  For example, if a player is instructed to decide how many points to give themselves, and more points is always better but the number declared is only attained if it satisfies some constraints involving public information from past game states, then the game could simply decide the optimal number a player suffering absentmindedness would choose, and the formula could take the player's strategy into account so that the player is incentivized to manage its encoding power.
Another sort of watered down option could be to throw so many similar events at a player in succession that they are actually prone to absentmindedness, but maybe counting isn't so (consistently) hard, and at any rate, this option is problematic because if the player actually forgets the current game state, then there will be no way to agree on it after the decision is made in order to progress the game.
Are there any more clever concrete game design tricks which can be used to mimic or get closer to the above strategic elements of the phenomenon of absentmindedness?

"there will be no way to agree on it after the decision is made in order to progress the game." What do you mean? Why does the player's ability to remember the game state matter for the game to progress? Isn't one feature of card and board games that the game state is represented by the various components?

@TheChaz2.0 I think not.  Most card and board games have both visibly and invisibly represented information.  For example, in Monopoly, there is no component used to represent how many turns someone has been in Jail, and in Magic, there is no component used to represent which phase/step the game state is in currently.  My point was that if a rule or effect said something like "Do X 100 steps from now" with note-taking illegal and the designer banking on the player losing track of the count in order to induce absentmindedness in a player's decision, then immediately after that decision

(if not before), there is almost certain to be difficult-to-resolve disagreement over the objective truth of the count and how to proceed with the game as a consequence.

I would suggest three potential approaches to achieve this:

Time constraints.  If players have to make a lot of decisions under a real-time constraint, they will not be able to keep track of them all.  You can do this either through hourglasses or by having the players race.  Egyptian Rat Screw is a game largely built around this.  Players need to make a decision to slap or not based on a quickly updating card stack and are penalized for both hesitating and slapping incorrectly.

Complexity overload. Have more state tracked by the board game than players can reasonably keep in their head.  For example, in Small World, players victory points are "secret"; the points a player gets is public information, and the number of face-down point tiles each player has is public (tiles may be 1, 5, or 10 points, but it's generally too burdensome to keep a running total of the points of each player in your head.  As a result, players have an approximate sense of who is winning but they don't know for sure.  You could leverage a similar mechanic for a number of states tracked by the game that are important for players to evaluate their decision matrix but players only have a fuzzy notion of the true value.

Randomness. If you want to model the exact confused driver problem and those like it, you can.  Have the player declare a strategy (best implemented as choosing one of several options) and then have the outcome of that be based on choosing one of the underlying states at random.  To use your confused driver example, a player could be presented with the payoff model of turning at various intersections, they make a decision about how they will turn, and then they roll a die to find out if they were at the first or the second intersection and collect points based on what their strategy said.


One general caveat: just because a game theory game is interesting to study does not mean it will be fun or interesting to play in a competitive fashion.  Game theory games really rely on players trying to maximize their score, where competitive games usually focus on players trying to outscore each other, and this can change the incentives.  For example, in a repeated prisoner's dilemma, players can do better from an absolute score perspective than always defecting by playing conditionally cooperative strategies like tit-for-tat; however, if you play "repeated prisoner's dilemma the 2 player game" where the goal is just to score higher than your opponent, all of the interesting pieces of this game go away and always defect becomes the dominant strategy.  In order to actually play a repeated prisoner's dilemma in a way that is fun, you need to embed it in a broader game (such as Diplomacy, which has a repeated prisoner's dilemma players' alliances that emerges out of the game rules and incentives).

I appreciate the point about game theory VS concrete games, and I consider this question highly exploratory, a matter of trying to understand how well the ideas behind absentmindedness can be ported rather than presuming.  I think the particular repeated prisoner's dilemma example is only problematic because it works by manipulating both players' payoffs, and in zero sum contexts all payoff gains for one player are equal losses for the other, whereas absentmindedness only needs to manipulate one player's payoffs.

I don't think the randomness idea preserves the strategic structure of the driver problem, because the expected values before playing would become the same as the expected values while playing (the driver problem arises because the strategy at the average of the intersections is a bad strategy at the first intersection).  Also, there would be no possibility of the driver at the first intersection encoding information for their future self.  The Small World example might end up going somewhere I'll think about it some more.

Possible Issues
The common ground for each game probably will be that understanding the game state is a good thing, so answering this question would in my opinion have to be tied to a specific intent. You need a good reason to introduce any such mechanic in order to avoid just making the game in question deliberately worse than it could be.
This reason, in turn, is important to answer the question. I'll loosely lean on @Zags' answer's approaches (which I very much agree with by the way) to illustrate my reasoning:

If your goal is to prevent analysis paralysis, you choose time constraints as a factor. For example, you tell the player that the 42nd intersection is the last one while quickly turning up tiles so that they will have no chance of counting intersections perfectly and will have to guess to a point. You likely gain speed and interactivity between players, but will get a game that will probably be received as a party game rather than a competitive one.
If your goal is to facilitate educated guesses, you choose secrecy as a factor. For example, each player holds cards that show a number of intersections, and from the amount of players, cards in their hands, and cards in your own hand, you can infer what the optimal intersection to choose might be. You gain a factor of engagement and rewarding knowledge of the game's mechanics, but you put newer players at a disadvantage in general while still allowing for sheer luck to decide games, rather than skill.
If your goal is to achieve unpredictability or gamling, you choose randomness as a factor. For example, draw cards from a deck to determine whether you hit another intersection or overplayed your hand. You likely gain positive uncertainty, but lose man aspects of skill, which in turn might not make the overall result very competitive in nature.

What all those reasons have in common is that they don't seem to benefit the overall goal of creating a competitive game, which at least from my understanding should reward skilled gameplay and reduce random or arbitrary outcomes to a minimum.
Possible Solutions
This raises the question whether there is a way to introduce the wanted amount of uncertainty without sacrificing those factors, effectively extending @Zags' list, which is why I'll stick to the same formatting:

Player-decided game state changes. We already hypothesized both that randomness can be a solution to the problem, as well as that there are issues with this approach. However, there is another way to achieve unpredictability, which is player actions. If both players have to react to each others' actions, each player will have to interact with a game state they cannot predict, effectively resulting in the same qualities as randomness, however will be much more compatible with competitive scenarios, as you are able to affect the new game state your opponent has to deal with, regardless of what their plans might have been. Examples that come to mind are The Matchstick Game and Connect Four, but really, this sort of interaction is very common in games.
Deciding on the objective after the action. One way of not just simulating but creating actual unawareness of the exact objective is if it isn't defined at the time you have to take your actions. This can be done as in Betrayal at House on the Hill where neither the role of the traitor nor the game's objective can be known in the first half of the game, or also in Cards Against Humanity, where you get points based on votes and therefore knowledge of the people at your table rather than a correct strategic decision with a peg on a board, but most importantly because of the tone set by the other cards played in this or previous rounds, making individual cards' values different in each game.
Rewarding intentional blind actions. The last take I can think of is offering the player to forego information in exchange for a certain reward, such as ingame currency. This in general introduces meaningful choice, but more importantly for the topic at hand, also encourages players to stay oblivious in exchange for more benefit in the remainder of the game. I can't come up with any exact example for this, but Sheriff of Nottingham does something similar enough perhaps.


For completeness' sake, I'll also mention the category of games that threaten absentmindedness, but do not enforce it, and instead reward you for overcoming it. What comes to mind are Simultaneous Exhibition games, as most commonly seen for Chess. While this borders on being similar enough to the complexity overload category, I believe the difference is that the player isn't meant to be drowned in a sea of information, but rather, the rules, game state, and strategy all are as "simple" as any regular game of Chess, but the player faces the challenge of testing their skill in a more complex way where you cannot hope to succeed if you lose track of even a single one of the played boards.

A fourth option is to explicitly pre-commit actions before knowing the circumstances those actions will be taken in. For example, in Killer Bunnies, players place some actions into a queue on their turn, and those actions trigger when they exit the queue on a future turn - but in the meantime, other actions have modified the game state in unexpected ways. (I believe Robo Rally does this as a central mechanic, and probably better than Killer Bunnies does, and I'd like to recommend it as an example but I haven't played it myself)

I have edited the question to make it more clear that that features of absentmindedness I originally highlighted in explaining the concept actually are the features which it is my intent to instantiate in a concrete game.

Make the player take meticulous, detailed, notes; or simulate the same by for example dropping items as markers. For instance, this now well-known game situation.

Of course, the player in this game quickly realizes that the Thief is acquiring all dropped items, necessitating an alternative strategy for maneuvering out of the "All Different" maze. Further along, the player encounters the "All Alike" maze:

If you require a player to be absentminded - then create a situation where the player's absent-mindedness is a natural consequence of the circumstances.
